# Unity Texture2D.ReadPixels() producing grey texture

Tags: unity-game-engine, texture2d

Here is my code:

```csharp
sigTex = new Texture2D ((int)dims.x, (int)dims.y);

sigTex.ReadPixels (new Rect (new Vector2(0.0f, Screen.height - bot) , dims), 0, 0);

byte[] pngBytes = sigTex.EncodeToPNG ();

System.IO.BinaryWriter bw= new System.IO.BinaryWriter(new System.IO.FileStream(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Create));
bw.Write (pngBytes, 0, pngBytes.Length);
bw.Close ();
```

The problem is that after this code I am left with a blank texture that is a uniform gray when I try to use it in GUI or view it in the inspector.
The strange thing is that the file produced is correct.

Comment: Can you provide the code with applying the texture on the UI elements?

Comment: I would believe that this is the problem if it wasn't for the fact that if I make the texture public I can se it is gray in the inspector and if I drop a texture in while running it displays. GUI.DrawTexture (new Rect (cursor, GUIConstanst.flatRect), sigTexture, ScaleMode.ScaleToFit);

Comment: If below answer helped, please consider ticking the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this. Ive added texture.Apply();

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.Apply.html

```
sigTex = new Texture2D ((int)dims.x, (int)dims.y);

sigTex.ReadPixels (new Rect (new Vector2(0.0f, Screen.height - bot) , dims), 0, 0);

sigTex.Apply();

byte[] pngBytes = sigTex.EncodeToPNG ();

System.IO.BinaryWriter bw= new System.IO.BinaryWriter(new System.IO.FileStream(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Create));
bw.Write (pngBytes, 0, pngBytes.Length);
bw.Close ();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was driving me mad. Now I look at the docs for Apply() it all makes sense. The texture in normal memory was being updated so that .EncodeToPNG() worked but it was not being moved to the GPU memory.